# CreateProcessAsUser is not working in Incognito/private window

Tags: java, jna, incognito-mode, waffle, createprocessasuser

Creating a new process from Java web application using **createProcessAsUser** and waffle SSO impersonation. Everything works fine in chrome and any other browsers normal window, when I try to access the web application using **incognito/private** window, new process is not created, but didn't get any errors or warnings. I don't see any difference when I run it in normal/private mode. Any insights would be greatly helpful.

Calling with:

```java
Advapi32.INSTANCE.CreateProcessAsUser(
    primaryToken.getValue(), 
    null,
    "" + batchFile + " " + workFlowId + " " + tokenAccount.name 
        + " >> " + fileName,
    null,
    null,
    false,
    WinNT.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE | WinNT.CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT, 
    environment,
    fileDirectory,
    startupInfo,
    processtartupInfo
)
```

Comment: Show us the code you're using.  Likely one of the arguments to the function (environment, perhaps) behaves differently.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Daniel Widdis! Code snippet:  ```Advapi32.INSTANCE.CreateProcessAsUser(primaryToken.getValue(), null,
     ""+batchFile+" "+workFlowId+" "+tokenAccount.name+" >> "+fileName, null, null, false, WinNT.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE | WinNT.CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT, environment,
     fileDirectory, startupInfo, processtartupInfo)```

If you need further details about the code, Please let me know!

Comment: Where does `environment` come from?  Can you add logging to your code and compare the values of the environment, startupInfo, processstartupInfo, etc.?   Find out which one is different for incognito.

Comment: @DanielWiddis Environment, startupInfo, processstartinfo values are similar in both the cases. But when experimented it by changing ImpersonationLevel of DuplicateTokenEx from SecurityImpersonation to *SecurityDelegation*. it started working fine! it seems to be strange:) Thanks a lot Daniel !

Answer (score 0):

**Change ImpersonationLevel of DuplicateTokenEx from SecurityImpersonation to SecurityDelegation**